# ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT on compute engine trying to run cloud-sql-proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to install and run cloud-sql-proxy on my compute engine instance.

When I run the command: ./cloud-sql-proxy xxx:us-central1:xxx-sql it returns this error:

Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
Details:

```
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "method": "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlConnectService.GetConnectSettings",
      "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com"
    },
    "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
  }
]
```

More details:
Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission

I'm having a hard time understanding the documentation. Which service do I need to be looking at and how do I grant the permissions?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the virtual machine instance's Access Scopes. The default settings do not allow Cloud SQL. Review this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you can double check is the VM's access scope.
Steps:

- Stop the VM that you ran proxy from
- Check the access scope by clicking on edit button of this VM. Check the "allow full access to all Cloud APIs"

[image]

- Restart the VM and try the proxy again.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but am still getting an error:  Error 403: boss::NOT_AUTHORIZED: Not authorized to access resource. Possibly missing permission cloudsql.instances.get on resource instances/xxxx-sql., forbidden

Comment: Make sure to add "roles/cloudsql.client" to your IAM principal -- in this case probably the default Compute Engine service account.

Answer (score 1):

This [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy#usage) contains all the information you need to use the Cloud SQL Proxy.

Please let us know if you have further questions.

Comment: Everything but details on correctly configuring the VM's Access Scopes when using the attached service account. I think that should be added to the documentation page that you referenced. Very common problem.

Comment: My compute engine default service account has these roles: Editor, Cloud SQL Admin.  Am I in the wrong spot?